# Devexpress TreeList - how can i delete value from a cell when it is set as readonly

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

I am using the devexpress TreeList control. In Treelist I have a situation where one of my column is read only. This column may have some text values added when something happens in another cell. I have restricted user entry in the cell by setting a property like this

```
    treeList1.Columns["col3"].OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = true;
```

Now I want to remove text value from some of the cells and since it is read only the delete buttons does not work. Can you suggest the event/method and the code which will allow user to delete the text?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the code you use to delete a cell value ?

Comment: Thanks SidAhmed for looking at my issue, honestly I am not sure what should I write to delete it. I think I have to write on some cell event and check if the key pressed is delete on that cell then delete the text. Just wondering if anybody know in which event I should write the code to delete the text value of a cell. I am also researching on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited solution :**

You should know that when the cursor is in the cell (in edit mode), and you press a button, it's not the `TreeList` who send the `KeyDown` event, but the `RepositoryItemButtonEdit`. So, you should handle the event also for the `RepositoryItemButtonEdit`.

To not duplicate code, I've wrote one handler '`onKeyDown`', in whitch I verify who is the sender.

```
treeList1.KeyDown += onKeyDown;
riButtonEdit.KeyDown += onKeyDown;
```

And here is a code exemple showing you how to handle the `KeyDown` event for both `treeList` and `repositoryButtonEdit`, and set the cell value to `null` :

```
private void onKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Test if the button pressed is the delete button
    if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Delete)
        return;

    // Test if the focused column is colValue
    if (treeList1.FocusedColumn != colValue)
        return;

    // Set the cell value to null
    treeList1.FocusedNode.SetValue(colValue, null);

    // If it's the ButtonEdit who send the event, make it's EditValue null
    var btnEdit = sender as ButtonEdit;
    if (btnEdit != null)
    {
        btnEdit.EditValue = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I made it read only because there is an icon in this cell which on click open a dialog box. Now when i set allowedit to false then that icon click doe not work so i had to make it read only therefore allowing user to click on the icon but restrict him to enter any text in this cell. You have given a solution as per my question and I'll accept/mark this as an answer. I would appreciate if you can suggest a workaround for a situation like this where user can click image as well as delete the existing text but not enter the text on his own. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is the code i wrote to show the image as well as text: 
                buttonEdit = new RepositoryItemButtonEdit();
                treeList1.ShowButtonMode = DevExpress.XtraTreeList.ShowButtonModeEnum.ShowAlways;
                buttonEdit.Buttons[0].Kind = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Glyph;
                buttonEdit.Buttons[0].Image = imageCollection2.Images[0];
                
                treeList1.ForceInitialize();

Comment: treeList1.Columns[colName].AppearanceCell.Options.UseTextOptions = true;
                treeList1.Columns[colName].AppearanceCell.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Far;                                
                buttonEdit.ButtonClick += new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventHandler(buttonEdit_ButtonClick);
                //treeList1.Columns[colName].OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false; 
treeList1.Columns[colName].OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = true;

Comment: I've edited the solution to fit your case, I've tested it and it works fine.